# TAB Event Filter forTextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to validate user input in JavaFX, so for my TextField i used event filter like below code

```
@FXML
private TextField textField;

@FXML
void initialize()
{
     textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, numeric_tab(textField.getText().toString()));
}



public EventHandler<KeyEvent> numeric_tab(String number)
{
    return new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
         @Override
         public void handle(KeyEvent e)
         {
             if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)
             {
                  System.out.println("Cursor is here");
                  System.out.println(number);
             }

         }
    };
}
```

As you can see i add an Event Filter for TextField so whenever a user press any key of keyboard we will go to numeric_tab method and inside that we check if the pressed key was Tab-Button, we should print the parameter which is passed by Event Filter.

But I've got problem, although my application prints "Cursor is here" on the console but it does not print the value of TextField. ( again let me say that the value of TextField has sent by event filter)

Why? Why i can't get entire value of the TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed to the filter is only set when the filter is added to the component. In your case the `TextField` is probably empty so nothing is displayed. To display the current contents you can simply invoke `getText`

```
System.out.println(textField.getText());
```

Comment: What a fool I am. But I can't understand although my TextField is not empty my code does not show anything, it seems a little strange. your answer works for me, but why my code does not work?

Comment: suspect that `initialize` is being called before the text is actually set (from FXML)...